# how to improve the performance of the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the **pdfmake** library in a project, but its execution takes about 2-3 min.
Is the library normally slow or do I need to improve the performance of my code ? 
It is also possible that performances are impacted by the code being executed in chunks, but I am not sure I understand the role of chunks and why they are used.

```
 var docDefinition = {
    footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
      return {
        margin: [40, 0, 0, 0],
        columns: [{
          fontSize: 8,
          text: [
            {
              text: 'Page ' + currentPage.toString() + ' / ' + pageCount,
            }
          ],
        }]
      };
    },
    content: contentAry,
    styles: {
      clsHeader: {
        fontSize: 12,
        bold: true
      },
      clsSubHeader: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      clsTblHeader: {
        fillColor: '#9e9e9e',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      },
      clsImage: {
        margin: [0, 40, 0, 0]
      },
      clsTable: {
        fontSize: 8
      }
    },
    defaultStyle: {
      alignment: 'justify'
    }
  }
  var doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
  var chunks = [];
  doc.on('readable', function () {
    var chunk;
    while ((chunk = doc.read(9007199254740991)) !== null) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
    }
  });
```

Is it possible to modify the chunk size?

Comment: which part of the code have you deteremined is *slow* - and what is this number **`9007199254740991`**

Comment: numbar is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER  it is (2^53 - 1).

Comment: which part of the code have you deteremined is slow  ? (again)

Comment: var doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition); this take 2-3 min

Comment: are you sure that printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition) is the one that takes time? i have a fealing that when you try to read it in readable event that is where preformance issue happens

Comment: Yes, I do recognise it is 2^53-1 .... but ... what does it mean

Comment: your code looks different to the example at https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/0.1/dev-playground/server.js

Comment: doc.on('data', function (chunk) {
  chunks.push(chunk);
 });
do you see that part thats the right event i think which is data and the chunck is sent throught it